# Align icon-font span with text span in line

Tags: html, css

I want to align an icon-font `<span>` tag with an text `<span>` in row. It seems if the two `<span>` are in line but the icon is somehow "floating" over the div.

```css
.navigation {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navigation .counter {
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navigation span {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navigation .material-icons {
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-semver="1.3.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="navigation">
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></span>
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i></span>
  <span class="counter">select floor</span>
</div>
```

So how can I align the icon and the text so that the text is in the vertical center of the icon ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `line-height` of the text needs to be the same as the `font-size` of the icon's. Using `vertical-align:middle;` in this way is not necessary.

```css
.navigation {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navigation .counter {
  background: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height:21px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.navigation span {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation .material-icons {
  font-size: 21px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-semver="1.3.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="navigation">
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></span>
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i></span>
  <span class="counter">select floor</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the following classes with `vertical-align` and `display` Properties:

**CSS**

```
     .navigation {
          padding-left: 50px;
          padding-top: 50px;
          padding-bottom: 50px;
          display: inline-block;
        }

      navigation .material-icons {
          font-size: 21px;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding **verical-align: middle to  .navigation .material-icons** will solve the issue.

```css
.navigation {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navigation .counter {
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navigation span {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navigation .material-icons {
  font-size: 21px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-semver="1.3.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="navigation">
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></span>
  <span><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i></span>
  <span class="counter">select floor</span>
</div>
```